# How does one go about solving complicated integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm reading a paper on behavior analysis which describes the arousal $A_t$ of an animal with
the following equation:

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRLgE.jpg)

In this equation, everything that is not *t* are parameters that can be considered to be constants. I am trying to find a simple formula for the integral of $A_t$ with respect to *t*. I have tried simplifying the equation as much as I can and I've tried integrating it through Wolfram Alpha, with no success. What kind of techniques do mathematicians generally use to integrate unusual functions such as these?

Comment: Bundle every term that is independent of $t$ into an appropriate constant.

Comment: Usually, you leave it written as an integral.  You do not try to "evaluate" it.  Very few formulas have integrals that can be evaluated in simple form.